Exclude standalone components depending on a build in Angular
I have two environments - one for testing and the second for the release. I have a standalone component that helps me with debugging, but I don't want to include this in the release build. How can I exclude it? I mean, my goal is not to hide it(behind any *ngIf flag) but completely remove it from the build.

Two possible ways:

Deferrable Views

You can use the deferrable views feature of Angular (https://angular.io/guide/defer).
You would be able to define something like:
@defer (when debugMode) {
  <your-component />
}

Where debugMode is you environment variable.
This is basically a lazy loading feature for components.

TsConfig File Exclude

you can actually exclude file from Angular build in the tsconfig.json:
"exclude": [
    "path/to/your/file.ts"
]

To use this you may want to have one tsconfig.json for the "production" build and one for the "debug" build that doesn't exclude the file.
Than update the angular.json to use the right tsconfig file for the build:
"fileReplacements": [
  {
    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
  },
  {
    "replace": "src/yourconfig.ts",
    "with": "src/yourconfig.prod.ts"
  }
],


nice answer! very detailed!

@defer doesn't work - if you check your main.ts file you'll see that this file is still in the code. Defer is used for lazy loading the component, not excluding it from the build permanently based on condition(devMode or env)
In terms of fileReplace I know this trick, but you have to keep two files - one for prod, second for dev. There must be something better

I don't think it's possible to exclude just a file from the compilation in any other way. Also there's the problem that you are referencing that component in your code so the compiler will try to resolve it and compile it.

ok fileReplace works only for the files that can pass regex; so it is env only solution. Can't accept the solution
EDIT: We post in the same moment. I'll look for something different

What do you mean by "so it is env only solution"? isn't what are you looking for anyway?

In Angular, you can configure the application for different environments. Read angular official documentation about it.

The best method is using "@defer (when isDevMode) {}" with "--configuration production" in the package.json. IsDevMode is a core function, "--configuration production" is one of the parameters of the "ng build" command.
@defer works only if the child and parent are standalone and the child doesn't contain stuff that is imported elsewhere(like const, enum, or interface)
The idea is to create a chunk of data(similar to lazyLoaded module) that won't be ever loaded, because of a result of the function. It can be modified to use .env variables.
Dead-code elimination/exclusion is being processed by Angular Team
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/51175
Thanks for help

You can complete the @n_denny first solution (deferrable views) with a production configuration file replacement
Your view:
@defer (when debugMode) {
   <your-component />
}

angular.json configuration
"configurations": {
 "production": {
  "fileReplacements": [
   {
    "replace": "src/app/your-component.component.ts",
    "with": "src/app/your-empty-component.component.ts"
   }
  ],
...

your-empty-component.component.ts is an empty angular component
